# Built-in option to select specific friends from friends list (checkboxes)?

Tags: php, facebook

I Googled around and couldn't find neither a built-in function nor one available for download.

I was wondering if there was a way to implement (into a Facebook app, using PHP) a list of friends to be selected from the current user's friends list, similar to the kind of checkbox-select pop-up you get when inviting friends to an event on Facebook.

I'd like to have the user select any number of friends from their list and have those friends' IDs stored in an array for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only built-in option Facebook has is the Requests Dialog, but this is for the specific purpose of sending request messages. See here for more info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Otherwise, you would likely have to do something yourself, which shouldn't be too hard to do.

Since you can access the user's friends list using:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=

This would give you a Json-formatted list of the user's friends and their ID's.

You used to be able to use FBML to generate a dialog pop-up:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/dialog/

However, FBML is being phased out, and I don't believe there's a replacement for this dialog yet, so you'll have to create your own, or take a risk and use the FBML markup (no idea if it still works).

Comment: I'm pretty sure FBML still works but I'm not going to use something that's being phased out. I think I really will just write up something myself, should be pretty simple. I just though maybe there was a built-in function. 
Thanks for the info.